# Tesseract.js with React: Tainted canvases may not be exported

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tesseract

I am currently trying to follow the example given to implement tesseract.js using React: `https://github.com/jeromewu/tesseract.js-react-app/blob/master/src/App.js.`

However, I keep getting the error:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'toBlob' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.
    at blueimpLoadImage.orientation
```

After a bit of research I have discovered it is to do with CORS, however I can't find a solution as the `worker.recognize('https://tesseract.projectnaptha.com/img/eng_bw.png');` function takes a url, not an img (which doesn't get displayed on the web page)

I am very confused and any help would be appreciated!!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

I face the same issue here. And base on my research, somehow the error appears when you I use Tesseract.js v2.1.4. I already report the issue in [Tesseract.js repo](https://github.com/naptha/tesseract.js/issues/514#issue-803733847). I hope they can fix it soon.

While waiting for the fix, I try to use Tesseract.js v2.0.0 and it works well in my project. In my react app folder I install it by running this command:

```
npm install tesseract.js@2.0.0
```